# Error in http connection javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate below jelly bean version

Tags: java, android, ssl, https

We are changed Http to https in admin panel we are calling that url in client side but problem is below ANDROID LOLLIPOP version is not working in http

```
06-09 15:48:11.130 17668-17859/com.sample.school E/NativeCrypto: Unknown error during handshake
06-09 15:48:11.152 17668-17859/com.sample.school E/log_tag: Error in http connection javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
06-09 15:48:11.153 17668-17859/com.sample.school E/log_tag: Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
06-09 15:48:11.349 17668-17859/com.sample.school E/NativeCrypto: Unknown error during handshake
06-09 15:48:11.483 17668-17859/com.sample.school E/Buffer Error: Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
06-09 15:48:11.484 17668-17859/com.sample.school E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
06-09 15:48:18.526 17668-17821/com.sample.school E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5524ec10 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x53f2bab8 arg=0x0
06-09 15:48:18.535 17668-17821/com.sample.school E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5524ec10 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
```

Answer (score 0):

dont listen to android_jain.

2017 you cant be without SSL.

ok so i tell you what i think is the the problem.

so all you need to do is just check in the device with the firmware that you getting the error if the certificate is found in the list of the certificates of the device.

how you do that?

go to settings -> security -> certificates

and then look for the name of your certificate in the list you just opened

https://whyhard.com

Comment: verifed By : geo trust inc